# SQL Server column of type varchar has dot and dash - on right side convert into Decimal

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

I have a string column which sample data like this:

```
14.377.616
29.264.814
16.892.140
6.410.850-
```

and I want output to be like this:

```
14377616.0000
29264814.0000
16892140.0000
-6410850.0000
```

The column must be converted to decimal. I have a query like this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN Column LIKE '%-%' 
        THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(Column, '-', ''), '.', '')
    WHEN Column LIKE '%-%' 
        THEN Column * -1
    ELSE CONVERT(decimal(20, 4), REPLACE([Column], '.', ''))
END
```

but result the negative cannot display dash in LEFT (but dash is gone) like this:

```
14377616.0000
29264814.0000
16892140.0000
6410850.0000
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just replace the dots with nothing and then convert? Or, better yet, not store numerical data as a string based data type on the first place?

Comment: can you give the query for your explain? thanks ...

Comment: [REPLACE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do in this way:

```
with CastedTable (MyColumn)
as
(
  select replace([Column],'.','') DecimalValue
  from MyTable
)
select 
  case 
  when MyColumn like '%-%' then cast('-' + replace(MyColumn, '-', '') as decimal(20, 4))
  else cast(MyColumn as decimal(20, 4)) end
from CastedTable
```

Results:

|  |
| --- |
| 14377616 |
| 29264814 |
| 16892140 |
| -6410850 |

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/decccb/8

That said, if you want to use your query, it would be this:

```
select  CASE 
  WHEN [Column] like '%-%' THEN CONVERT(decimal(20,4),REPLACE(REPLACE([Column],'-',''),'.','')) * -1
  ELSE CONVERT(decimal(20,4),REPLACE([Column],'.','')) END AS [Column]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `right()` to get + or - and replace dots using `replace()` like this

***note*:** `'13123.123123'` -> `colname`

```
select 
 CASE WHEN  RIGHT ( '13123.123123' , 1) <> '-' THEN
 CAST ( REPLACE('13123.123123','.','') AS decimal)
 ELSE
  CAST ( REPLACE('13123.123123','.','') AS decimal) * -1
  END
```